# How do I get rid of the following npm error?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-start

Whenever I run "npm" on the terminal I get the following error:

```
$ npm
node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 933
const err = new Error(message); ^

Error: Cannot find module './functions/valid'
Require stack:

C:\Users\ CTF\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ semver\ index.js
C:\Users\ CTF\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ npm\ lib\ cli.js
C:\Users\ CTF\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ npm\ bin\ npm - cli.js
at Function.Module._resolveFilename(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 933: 15)
at Function.Module._load(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 778: 27)
at Module.require(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1005: 19)
at require(node: internal / modules / cjs / helpers: 102: 18)
at Object. < anonymous > (C: \Users\ CTF\ AppData\ Roaming\ npm\ node_modules\ npm\ node_modules\ semver\ index.js: 12: 10)
at Module._compile(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1103: 14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1157: 10)
at Module.load(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 981: 32)
at Function.Module._load(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 822: 12)
at Module.require(node: internal / modules / cjs / loader: 1005: 19) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: [
        'C:\Users\CTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\semver\index.js',
        'C:\Users\CTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js',
        'C:\Users\CTF\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    ]
}
```

I tried to re-install nodejs but that didn't work, the error still pops up.

Comment: please improve the title of your question. No one will search for "the following error". The idea is that your question can help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install node with nvm ?

- Uninstall NodeJS
- Remove directories `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm` & `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` if remaining
- Install nvm
- Install node with nvm

Answer (score 0):

To clarify Thomas H's Answer

1. Uninstall node
2. Download nvm from this link https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.9/nvm-setup.exe and install it
3. Install node using this command `nvm install latest`
4. Note: make sure you completely remove: `npm` and `npm-cache` directories from this path  `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming`, you can use  `Everything windows application` to search for the path